# Display a list of editable properties

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a grid of settings for the user to edit. I'm using a [`PropertyGrid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid(v=vs.110).aspx) at the moment, but I'm open to alternative solutions.

My two big issues are that I don't love the look of the property grid. It looks overly complex for the small number of properties that can be edited. Also, I dislike how verbose it is to add a new property. Which brings me to my second issue. The code for `errorLogFile` and `syncLogFile` are 99% duplicated. Is there a way to make them use a shared function (or something similar) and just pass in the name of the log?

I also welcome any general critiques of style. I come from a Python background, but I'm trying to get in the habit of C#'s idioms.

```
using Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using NLog.Targets;
using NLog;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Status_Sync
{
    public partial class SettingsDialog : Form
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
        private SyncProperties syncProperties = new SyncProperties();
        public SettingsDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SettingsDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            propertyConfigGrid.SelectedObject = new SyncProperties();
        }

        private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((SyncProperties)propertyConfigGrid.SelectedObject).Save();
            Close();
        }
    }

    internal class SyncProperties
    {
        private string clientConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["clientConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        [ReadOnly(false)]
        [EditorAttribute(typeof(ConnectionStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        public string ClientConnectionString
        {
            get { return clientConnectionString; }
            set { clientConnectionString = value; }
        }

        private string serverConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["serverConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        [ReadOnly(false)]
        [EditorAttribute(typeof(ConnectionStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        public string ServerConnectionString
        {
            get { return serverConnectionString; }
            set { serverConnectionString = value; }
        }


        private string localLoginName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalLoginName"];
        [ReadOnly(false)]
        public string LocalLoginName
        {
            get { return localLoginName; }
            set { localLoginName = value; }
        }

        private FileTarget syncLogFile = (FileTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("syncLog");
        private string syncLogFileName;
        [ReadOnly(false)]
        public string SyncLogFileName
        {
            get
            {
                // If the user has set a custom log file name, we want to return that. Otherwise we return the current position of the log file.
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(syncLogFileName)) { return syncLogFileName; };
                string logPath = ((FileTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("syncLog")).FileName.Render(new LogEventInfo { TimeStamp = DateTime.Now });
                if (logPath != Path.GetFullPath(logPath))
                {
                    string executablePath = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;
                    return Path.Combine(executablePath, logPath);
                }
                else
                {
                    return logPath;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                syncLogFileName = value;
            }

        }

        private FileTarget errorLogFile = (FileTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("errorLog");
        private string errorLogFileName;
        [ReadOnly(false)]
        public string ErrorLogFileName
        {
            get
            {
                // If the user has set a custom log file name, we want to return that. Otherwise we return the current position of the log file.
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorLogFileName)) { return errorLogFileName; };
                string logPath = ((FileTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("errorLog")).FileName.Render(new LogEventInfo { TimeStamp = DateTime.Now });
                if(logPath != Path.GetFullPath(logPath))
                {
                    string executablePath = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;
                    return Path.Combine(executablePath, logPath);
                }
                else
                {
                    return logPath;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                errorLogFileName = value;
            }

        }

        public void Save()
        {
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["serverConnectionString"].ConnectionString = serverConnectionString;
            config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["clientConnectionString"].ConnectionString = clientConnectionString;
            config.AppSettings.Settings["LocalLoginName"].Value = localLoginName;
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
            errorLogFile.FileName = ErrorLogFileName;
            syncLogFile.FileName = SyncLogFileName;
            LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
        }
    }

    class ConnectionStringEditor: UITypeEditor
    {
        public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
        }

        public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
        {
            using(DataConnectionDialog dialog = new DataConnectionDialog())
            {
                DataSource.AddStandardDataSources(dialog);
                DialogResult userChoice = DataConnectionDialog.Show(dialog);
                if(userChoice == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    return dialog.ConnectionString;
                }
                else
                {
                    return value;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is too complex because you're dealing with too many classes in one file. Because Visual Studio creates the necessary structure to build multiple files into a DLL or an executable image, you shouldn't create all your classes in a single file. If the class can be used in other projects you are dragging too many things with it.

Rather than creating an inner class, you can use an `interface` to provide the public methods. Visual Studio will make creating the `interface` very quick and easy. The `interface` will hide the structure of the class.

From the looks of things you can create a class called LogFile and errorLogFile and syncLogFile can be instances of that class. The LogFile class should be in another source code file.

Comment: Yeah, I need to get into the habit of breaking things further out into types/classes. Should I generally only have one class per file?

Comment: That what's common.

Comment: This resolved my issues with DRY and complexity. Do you have any thoughts on the PropertyGrid? Is there a better control if I'm only going to be displaying a handful of properties? Is there any other controls that will do the same "Display a dynamic set of editable properties"? If you can address that, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I'm sorry Morgan, I'm not really up to date on Windows Forms.

Comment: All good. Unless an answer addressing that as well comes in soon, I'll accept yours. This has been very helpful, thanks.